# Why does console.log add a space at the end of my sentence, when adding a value with the comma operator?

Tags: javascript

This question is almost not worth asking, but here I am.

Referencing the question above, here is the code and output

`var port = 3000`

`console.log("Listening on port ", port)`

Outputs `"Listening on port  3000"`

Notice the extra space thrown in there. Why does this occur?

Comment: Remove the space from the string, `console.log` already does that for you.

Comment: Because that's what `console.log` does. Might as well ask why it prints on the console instead of painting your bathroom blue. (Because the latter is *not* what it does). :) If you don't want the space, use `+` operator to stitch strings together.

Comment: @Amadan Lol fair enough. This is actually the answer I was looking for. I understand the difference between `,` and `+`, and I wasn't looking for how to correct it. Only *why* it does that. Thanks to other answerers though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By popular demand, copied from comments:

Because that's what console.log does. Might as well ask why it prints on the console instead of painting your bathroom blue. (Because the latter is not what it does). :) If you don't want the space, use + operator to stitch strings together.

The reason is, likely, the fact that `console.log`, at least in graphical clients, has the ability to present objects and arrays inline. This makes the displayed result not really a string, but more of a table, with the space separating each cell from another. Each argument is, thus, presented separately.

Also, considering that `console.log` is used for debugging, `console.log(i, j, a[i][j], a[i][j] / 2)` showing `3724.712.35` is not really all that useful, when compared to `3 7 24.7 12.35`. And writing `console.annoying_log(i + ' ' + j + ' ' + a[i][j] + ' ' + a[i][j] / 2)` is annoying. I had enough of that from Java, when I was younger.

Comment: It would be nice if when an object is placed after a comma, it put it on a new line; much easier to read and explore. I'm looking for how to make that comma separator use newline instead of space, but it only brought me here.

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log the method `log` takes as arguments a list of Javascript objects

> console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN);

You're right in the documentation it says that the objects are appended together but it doesn't say that the separator is a single space.

> obj1 ... objN A list of JavaScript objects to output. The string
>   representations of each of these objects are appended together in the
>   order listed and output.

Answer (score 1):

Should be be doing

```
 console.log("Listening on port " + port)
```

As (I think) it might be treating the arguments as an array and thus join it together with a default delimiter being a space

Comment: Not quite. The arguments are each independent, not joined. With object arguments, `console.log` can show the structure of the object. The thing that gets displayed is not really a string, but more like a table, and you're seeing the invisible padding between the cells :)

Comment: @Amadan If you throw an answer up there combining your two comments I will gladly accept that as the answer I was looking for.